# Fetch and display data on React bootstrap Table

Tags: django, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

Hello guys i am trying to display my data from my api 
here my Json response :

```
 {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Chicken Wings",
    "product_category": {
        "name": "Starter"
    },
    "short_description": "Delicious Chicken Wings",
    "image": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/meal_images/telechargement.jpeg",
    "price": 10
},
{
```

This is my react component for the table :

```
  <BootstrapTable data={this.state.todos} striped hover>
        <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id'>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name' filter={ { type: 'TextFilter', delay: 1000 } }>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='product_category' filter={ { type: 'TextFilter', delay: 1000 } }>Category</TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='image'> Image </TableHeaderColumn>
        <TableHeaderColumn dataField='price'> Price </TableHeaderColumn>
      </BootstrapTable>
```

but for 'product_category' that display me '{object} {object} , i try to display the name of the product_category , i tried with dataField='product_category.name' but dosen't work how can i access to the name of my product_category table ? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dataFormat` property for single `TableHeaderColumn` to format specific data in cell. You have data of type `Object` for product category cell, so the right data formatting for this cell will be: `dataFormat={ (cell) => cell.name }`.

Here is how will look like the whole table component:

```
<BootstrapTable data={this.state.todos} striped hover>
    <TableHeaderColumn isKey dataField='id'>ID</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='name' filter={ { type: 'TextFilter', delay: 1000 } }>Name</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='product_category' dataFormat={ (cell) => cell.name } filter={ { type: 'TextFilter', delay: 1000 } }>Category</TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='image'> Image </TableHeaderColumn>
    <TableHeaderColumn dataField='price'> Price </TableHeaderColumn>
  </BootstrapTable>
```